# How do we access the second last copied stuff on our clipboard?

Tags: windows, clipboard

How do we access the second last copied stuff on our clipboard?

(Windows Vista Home Premium 32-bit sp2)

I am still interested if the solution is not a straightforward one and requires *hacks*

Comment: actually i want it built in. because i prefer not to have just another prog just to do it.

Comment: So why do you accept an answer that has no "built-in" solution?

Comment: @slhck: Because it *is* the right answer.

Comment: @slhck because there isn't a built-in solution. so that's the next best answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default clipboard manager in Windows Vista does not keep track of history. Whenever you add something new to the clipboard, you overwrite what was already in there.

To prevent this behavior you need a third-party solution.

Ditto, http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net, seems like a very good clipboard manager with a lot of fancy features. It has received some pretty good reviews.

Answer (score 5):

[**ClipX**](http://bluemars.org/clipx/) is another one (use the eternal-beta versions).  I set `WinKey` + `V` to `Paste` the second from last clipboard entry.